# Junit with EJB - EJBException: Unable to instantiate container with factories []

Tags: junit, ejb, jboss7.x

I'm newbie in EJB.

I'm trying to test a simple EJB project with JBoss 7.1. But test throws Exception:

> javax.ejb.EJBException: Unable to instantiate container with factories
>   [] at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBCont
>   ainer.java:97) at
>   javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBCont
>   ainer.java:75) at com.pack.HelloTest.test(HelloTest.java:17) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(
>   FrameworkMethod.java:47) at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(Refl
>   ectiveCallable.java:12) at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(Fr
>   ameworkMethod.java:44) at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(
>   InvokeMethod.java:17) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271 ) at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit
>   4ClassRunner.java:70) at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit
>   4ClassRunner.java:50) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java: 63) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java :236) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java: 53) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java: 229) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.r
>   un(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(Test
>   Execution.java:38) at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTe
>   sts(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTe
>   sts(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(R
>   emoteTestRunner.java:390) at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(
>   RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

This is the test:

```
package com.pack;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.junit.Test;

public class HelloTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws NamingException {
         EJBContainer container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(); // line 17, throws javax.ejb.EJBException

          // Note that global naming isn't working yet.
          InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
          Hello bean = (Hello) ctx.lookup("HelloBean/local");

          String now = new Date().toString();
          String actual = bean.sayHello(now);

          assertEquals("Hello " + now, actual);

          container.close();
    }
}
```

Project has a bean HelloBean:

```
package com.pack;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class HelloBean
 */
@Stateless
public class HelloBean implements Hello {

    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

}
```

And this is interface Hello:

```
package com.pack;

public interface Hello {
    String sayHello(String name);
}
```

Could you tell me how to fix this error, please?

Comment: As stated in [the Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/embeddable/EJBContainer.html#createEJBContainer()), an EJBException gets thrown if the container or application could not be successfully initialized. [This NetBeans bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=191554) seems to suggest it is an existing bug of NetBeans that is not yet fixed. Maybe a solution can be found if you try some of the advice in [this JBoss Developer Forum thread (How to Junit test EJB class)](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/163595)? (e.g. someone suggests using JBoss Arquillian)